# Setting up cron job to execute a PHP Script

Tags: php, ios, cron, push-notification

I need to setup a cron job that'll execute a PHP script (used to send iPhone notification to users) every minute. I've tried several code snippets but none of them seem to work. Here's what I've tried:

```
crontab -e
```

then..in the editor, i typed

```
* * * * * php  /Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php
```

but it doesn't work. I'm running on Mac OS X Lion and will be deploying the service on Linux service but i think the crontab ability shouldn't quite be affected by the OS as both are based on unix core. So, anyway, I need this cronjob to fire `simplepush.php` every minute to send notifications. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running php /Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php in the terminal to check if it's working?

Comment: Btw, for the cronjob to run every minute, this is the syntax: */1 * * * *

Comment: Try checking your cron mail logs by using mail in the terminal. I think that's default behavior for osx using cron. Maybe there a some cron errors there

Comment: yeah..what do u want me to check in the mail log in the terminal?

Comment: on the top of your cron file, put MAILTO=youremailaddress . this way all the errors will be sent to your cron for better debuggin.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
* * * * * wget -q  /Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php
```

or

```
* * * * * wget -o  /Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php
```

Comment: yep..i tried it without the crontab..using php PATH/TO/MY/FILE and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this works for me in OSX Yosemite

`*/1 * * * * php -q /Users/path/to/php-file.php`